# query WHERE id='.$_GET['selected"] not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql

I need to allow my user to choose an option value in a dropdown list, upon which the page will refresh and columns from the DB will be update on the page. How can I set this behavior?

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
        // this js autorehresh page if option was change

        function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
        eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
        if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
        }
        </script>

     <?php
          //at first we must connect to DB
          //external
     require ('connectDB.php');
     ?>

     <form method="post">
        <select name="selected" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,1)">
        <?php
        **// echo all id in table to options dropdown menu**
          $sql='SELECT id FROM lekcia1';
            $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($db));
            $a = 0;
            while ($recording=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              $a ++;
              echo '<option value="'.$recording['selected'].'"> '.$a.' </option>';
            };
          ?>
        </select>
      </form>

      **<?php
        // query NOT WORK 
        $sql1='SELECT * FROM lekcia1 WHERE id='.$_GET['']; // Notice: Undefined index: selected
        $result1=mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error($db));
        $recording1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
      ?>**

      <ul>
        <li><?php echo $recording1['column1'];?></li>
        <li><?php echo $recording1['column2'];?></li>
        <li><?php echo $recording1['column3'];?></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: can you explain why it should work? at the time line is executed - nothing is selected in box and $_GET is empty

Comment: Try changing `$_GET['selected']` to `$_POST['selected']`

Comment: And put single quotation marks around your query values. On second thought change this line `$sql1='SELECT * FROM lekcia1 WHERE id='.$_GET['selected'];` to `$sql1="SELECT * FROM lekcia1 WHERE id='".$_POST['selected']."'";` You specify the `get` for the attribute at the form. Use `post` on the php part if you want to make use of that. Don't switch halfway in.

Comment: @TomKriek stop giving bad advices, `"` doesnt make any difference or sense here, instead - tell to avoid mysql_* functions and use escaping to prevent sql injections

Comment: @Lashane I added in `'` for the value. The `"` is just my way of syntax for queries ofcourse it's not canon. And yes @Majo Mrva like @Lashane said don't use `mysql_*` but `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: @TomKriek don't use `'` or `"` for integer values in sql queries, if it is your style - change it, also note - that form's method is not important, as actual query is done via GET in js function

Comment: @Lashane What would happen then if one of my variables would contain let's say `table` or `time` , from my experience this would conflict with the syntax. Also I did not know about the js part I'm here for the php. This question doesn't have a javascript tag in it. In my opinion it's better to put `'` around values and escape them properly or use parameter binding.

Comment: @TomKriek for string literals - use escaping (mysqli_real_escape..), for numeric - use intval or floatval

Comment: @Lashane Alright I will try that next time thanks for the pointers!

Comment: same wrong notice ...

Comment: $sql1="SELECT * FROM lekcia1 WHERE id='".$_POST['selected']."  BAD SYNTAX

Answer (score 0):

The query is still no-working so here is my correct code.

```
<html>
<head>

 <script language="JavaScript">
  // this js autorehresh page if option was change
 function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
 eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
 if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
  }
 </script>

  </head>
<body>
  <?php
  $host='localhost';    // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ
  $dbname='phpmyadmin'; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project
  $user='root';         // the USERNAME that you created, or were given, to access your database
  $password='';         // the PASSWORD that you created, or were given, to access your database
  $db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Neda sa pripojit k MySQL serveru: " . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($dbname, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
  mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');
  mysql_query('SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=uft8_general_ci');
  ?>

 <form method="post">
    <select name="selected" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,1)">
    <?php
    // echo all id in table to options dropdown menu**
      $sql='SELECT id FROM lekcia1';
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($db));
        $a = 0;
        while ($recording=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $a ++;
          echo '<option value="'.$recording['selected'].'"> '.$a.' </option>';
        };
      ?>
     </select>
   </form>

     <?php
    // query NOT WORK
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM lekcia1 WHERE id='".$_POST['selected']."'"; // Notice: Undefined index:        selected
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error($db));
    $recording1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
  ?>


  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $recording['nazov_lekcie'];?></li>
    <li><?php echo $recording['cislo_ulohy'];?></li>
    <li><?php echo $recording['nazov_ulohy'];?></li>
  </ul>
  <?php
  //at first we must connect to DB
  //external
  //require ('connectDB.php');
  ?>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: **change**                                               $sql1="SELECT * FROM lekcia1 WHERE id='".$_POST['selected']."'";                                         **to**                                                                  $sql1="SELECT * FROM lekcia1 WHERE id=$_POST['selected']";

Comment: Hmmm...
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)